# Not taking input by getchar() or it might be error in do while?

Tags: c, do-while, getchar

My program below isn't taking input using `getchar()`. Instead, it ends after printing, `"want to continue??(press y for yes and press n to reenter)"`. It doesn't take input after typing `n` or `N`.

```
void main(){
    int i,arr[]={55,10,23,11,35,8,9,20},n;
    char a;
    printf("Given array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
        do{
            printf("\nEnter position where you want to insert element:");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            printf("You entered position %d \n",n);
            printf("want to continue ??(press y for yes and press n to reenter)");
            a=getchar();
        } while(a=='n' || a=='N');
}
```

Comment: try `getchar();a=getchar();` or `scanf(" %c", &a);` because receive newline of `scanf("%d",&n);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , That,my friend, is a perfectly valid answer. Why post it as a comment?

Comment: `a` should be an `int` not a `char`.

Comment: @CoolGuy it have  been repeated already similar question many times in this site. The poor in value as knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to reference:[getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/)

> Returns the next character from the standard input (stdin).

Note that the standard input is a **buffered** I/O, so getchar() reads the first char in input buffer

when in `scanf("%d",&n);` you will input an int and a newline， then getchar() just read the newline

use `scanf("%d\n", &n);` instead, or as @BLUEPIXY said, add a `getchar();` before `a = getchar();`

more detailed explanations about input buffer: [Flush the input buffer](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392)

Answer (score -1):

You can add this before `a = getchar();`

```
getchar();
```

So this 'eats' the new line character from the buffer. Because after you entered a number e.g. 3 into `scanf("%d",&n);` there is still a `'\n'` in the buffer and if you only have this: `a = getchar();`, \n gets read in